# The customizable field is not saving to the database in Joomla

Tags: joomla, field, custom-fields

Good Morning. I have a conflict problem in my customizable field in a Joomla project. Basically, I created a customizable * type *, so that I could put a mask on * input *, but it doesn't save the data in the database, when I change the type to standard text, it saves the data. Another thing is that it doesn't give any error, it just doesn't send it to the database. Someone help me please? Here is the code below a field of mine from an input field for a phone: Don't worry if some words are in Portuguese, basically the functionality is the same as a normal code.

**

> telefone.php

**

```
<?php  

//AVISO DE RESTRIÇÃO
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Essa página não pode ser acessada diretamente');

jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldTelefone extends JFormField{

    //A CLASSE DO CAMPO DEVE CONHECRER SEU PRÓPRIO TIPO PELA VARIÁVEL '$type' E O FIELD ESPECÍFICO PRECISA TER ESSE TYPE
    protected $type = 'Telefone';

    //RETORNAR O INPUT E SEUS ATRIBUTOS, O TIPO DE RETORNO PRECISA SER UM CÓDIGO HTML
    public function getInput(){

        $inputHtml = "

        <!--IMPORTAÇÀO JAVASCRIPT-->
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js'></script>

        <input type='text' placeholder='(00) 0 0000-0000' id='telefone' required >

        <script>
        $('#telefone').mask('(00) 00000-0000');
        </script>";

        return $inputHtml;

    }

}

?>
```

**

> teste.xml

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form>
    <fieldset addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_teste/models/fields">
        <field
                name="telefone"
                type="telefone"
                label="Telefone: *"
                description="Telefone do usuário"
                size="40"
                class="inputbox"
                default=""
                />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.